# MySQL SELECT Command does find one entry less

Tags: php, mysql, select

here is my problem.

```
function getSent($id) {
    include 'dbh.php';
    $data = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * from message WHERE senderid='$id'";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

In the theory this method is picking all messages (in this case), but it always find one message less than in the db => If I drop the whole table, I will get an array with the size of 0.

How could I fix this?

Comment: By removing the line before while loop that throws away the first result

Comment: As Sami said, remove : `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`. You are fetching one row, then looping to fetch the rest of the data and you don't store the first fetch. 
`